# How to mouseover / hover for one item in a list in Vue?

Tags: vue.js

I have this vue which render a list of fruits using `v-for`. When I mouseover, the css class `hovering` applies to all items instead of just one item. How do I fix it to the css class `hovering` to apply to just the item I mouseover?

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    fruits: ['apple','kiwi', 'orange'],
    isHovering: false
  }
})
```

```css
.hovering{
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="fruit in fruits" @mouseover="isHovering = true" 
      @mouseout="isHovering = false" 
      :class="{hovering: isHovering}">
     {{ fruit }}
    </li>
  </ul>  
</div>
```

Comment: Have you considered using the [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) pseudo-class instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Erase the ":class="{hovering: isHovering}"" and use the common CSS pseudoclass ":hover" instead, like this:

```
<template>
<div id="app">
    <ul>
      <li v-for="fruit in fruits" class="hover" :key="fruit" @mouseover="isHovering = true" 
        @mouseout="isHovering = false" >
      {{ fruit }}
      </li>
    </ul> 
  </div>
</template>
```

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    fruits: ['apple','kiwi', 'orange'],
    isHovering: false
  }
})
```

```
<style>
.hover:hover{
  color: red
}

</style>
```